# how to create dependency free script?

Tags: malware, exploit, exploit-development

I have a script which can exploit a specific vulnerability. This script works well with the latest system but in the older systems it failed to run because of dependency (glibc-2.14). So how can i make it dependency free so that i can run it without dependency issue?

Comment: Really, what you want to do is *statically* link in libraries, rather than dynamically link them.  You can find much more about that on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This link https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63758 explains it very well.

Basically, compile a new version on the system.